# Is there an effective way to do page caching if I have multiple layouts based on device?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 3.1 application that has a landing page that I'd like to cache at the page level.  I understand that there are a number of techniques for this, and the one that is most appealing is to cache the controller index action that represents the landing page.  This page doesn't have any user authentication, and would be the same for all users until the cache is swept.

However, I have both a mobile layout and a non-mobile layout, with the application_controller detecting the presence of a mobile user agent, and setting an appropriate layout based on the user agent.  Is it possible to use page caching in this case, or am I stuck doing fragment caching to support the two layouts?  Alternatively, is there a better strategy for rendering separate mobile content that would make page caching easier?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Responsive Web Design http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples to create a design that works for all platforms.